# Why did the CF-105 cease production when it had such promising potential?

Tags: fighter, supersonic, canada

I have been reading about the CF-105 recently and noticed that although it was one of the most advanced aircraft of its era it was shut down by the Canadian government after one crashed in a freak accident that was caused by another aircraft and I was wondering if anyone knew if Canada had any better reasons for shutting it down or if it was just  bad move by the government?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason is the same as why many other jetfighters of that era were cancelled, the XB-70 being another emblematic example.

The reason is easy and came (more or less) unexpected, with the Arrow already pointing us into the right direction: "*The first Arrow Mk. 1, RL-201, was rolled out to the public on 4 October 1957, the same day as the launch of Sputnik I*".

The scientific-political consequences of the Sputnik were [quite broad](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sputnik_1#Reception), with the USA for example creating the [DARPA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DARPA) and  changing [NACA into NA**S**A](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creation_of_NASA#Transition_from_NACA_to_NASA).

And many of the jetfighters under development in that period were simply cancelled since "*it was believed the need for a manned interceptor of very high performance simply did not exist as the Soviets were moving their strategic force to ICBMs*". Natural selection.

Comment: +1  The UK cancelled the TSR-2 in part because Defence Minister Duncan Sandys' view in the 1957 Defence White Paper was that "the era of manned combat was at an end"